# Kill idle apache processes if they consume too much memory

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a few HTTP requests that results in some heavy memory usage (running a Python Django app with mod-wsgi).
My problem is that these processes seems to be lying around idle for a while.

Is there a way to tell apache to kill an idle process that have consumed X megabytes of memory?
The request have already been successfully handled.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't at the moment. What you can do though is delegate the specific URLs which have large transient memory usage to a separate mod_wsgi daemon process group which has inactivity timeout set on it so that if the requests for that URL is infrequent, when the process isn't used for a while it will restart the process and reclaim memory. If there is no inactive time long enough to trigger an inactivity timeout, you can instead use maximum requests and recycle it every so often based on number of requests.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess main processes=3 threads=5
WSGIDaemonProcess memory-hungry-1 threads=5 inactivity-timeout=60
WSGIDaemonProcess memory-hungry-2 threads=5 maximum-requests=20

WSGIProcessGroup main
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</Location /memory/hungry/url-1>
WSGIProcessGroup memory-hungry-1
</Location>

</Location /memory/hungry/url-2>
WSGIProcessGroup memory-hungry-2
</Location>
```

In other words, vertically partition your WSGI application to run across multiple daemon process groups. This allows you then to customise the processes/threads and other daemon specific settings in a way that matches what that specific part of the application requires.